# Form posted values depends on textbox input length

Tags: php, css

I have two php files: Form.php and NoForm.php

In Form.php I have:

```
<span style="position:relative; left:10px;"><input type="text" id="fName" name="fName">
<span style="position:relative; left:155px;"><input type="text" id="gName" name="gName">
</span></span>
<hr>
<span style="position:relative; left:10px;">Family name <span style="position:relative; left:242px;">Given name</span></span>
<br>
```

When I submit the form, I get in NoForm.php the values with the $_POST method.

Then, in NoForm.php I have:

```
<div id="familyName" style="position:relative; left:10px; float:left;"><?php echo $_POST['fName'];?></div> <span style="position:relative; left:350px;"><div id="givenName"><?php echo $_POST['gName'];?></div></span>
<hr>
<span style="position:relative; left:10px;">Family name <span style="position:relative; left:242px;">Given name</span></span>
```

The problem that I have is that I want that in NoForm.php, the family name and the given name starts just above the Given name and Family name label, but the position changes as a function of textbox input length.

Any advice?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

What I did is changing the divs of NoForm.php by .

Now these textbox are fixed regardless the input value.